# Share component instance - Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a component called "popover" that creates a black transparent background for the content it displays. It attaches itself to the DOM with an absolute position to the parent element. In addition to that, it does a number of things

- closes itself when you click outside
- resizes on dom events
- and a few other things.. not essential for my question.

So, it essentially creates this styling for the content and displays whatever content you pass in it using `ng-content`;

Sample usage

`<popover [(show)]="true" [width]="200">YOUR CONTENT</popover>`

The show defaults to false. The parent component can then dynamically set it to true when it needs to show the popover.

Now, I am running into a situation where I want to use this component in a `*ngFor` which is creating a table like structure with mulitple columns and each row can have 3/4 elements using this popover and the number of rows can keep growing > 50. So that means 100 or more popovers hanging around that are hidden.

What I was thinking was if I could create a shared instance of this popover to be used because it essentially displays content that's passed to it (I don't need to worry about it's positioning - it is configured to dynamically read the parents position and accordingly attach to the DOM). So the idea would be only 1 instance is created and this instance would just display the content whenever you hover an element that needs it. Is it possible to do it Angular4?

The idea is to prevent creation

`Angular version I am using: 4.2.6 (latest)`

Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, what you wanto to do can be acheived leveraging Dependency Injection.
You may wanto to look at Dialog of Angular Material (https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) as a font for inspiration.

Comment: could you be more elaborate please? I mean give an example? Thanks